# Arduino and a FSK Demodulator IC?

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit

I am really trying to get a decent wireless system with my arduino + amateur radio. I found this IC that decodes FSK signals, and was wondering if it could help me with decoding AFSK 1200baud signals. The IC is the [NJM2211](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/N/J/M/2/NJM2211.shtml). I have no idea how the IC works, how to get it timed correctly, or what it outputs out of that pin.

Should I go this direction? Would this IC help me?

Comment: You might like: https://www.argentdata.com/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=22&products_id=136

Comment: Do I see an avr ic on that thing? Wish they'd just release the code for it... Would really love to see how they pulled it off cleanly.

Comment: The TCM3105 is another old FSK modem chip that was very commonly used with microcontrollers.  Here is an [article from QST](http://www.cmlmicro.com/assets/614_TCM3105.pdf) that compares the TCM3105 with a slightly different replacement, the MX614.  This example shows connecting directly to a PCs RS-232 port.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can decode the signals in software using the Arduino. See [Arduino TNC](https://sites.google.com/site/ki4mcw/Home/arduino-tnc).

The software to do this is open source, [BeRTOS](http://www.bertos.org/use/examples-projects/arduino-aprs/).

Here is the hardware interface:

[image]